# need a help with if:else conditions cck

Tags: entities

```
function ruh_microblog_item($node) {
  $profile = content_profile_load('profile', $node->uid);
  $ava = theme_imagecache('microblog', $profile->field_photo[0]['filepath']);
  $noava = theme_imagecache('microblog', 'sites/default/files/imagecache/user_block_small/imagefield_default_images/no_photo.png');
  $content .= '<div id="mwrapper">';
  $content .= l($ava, 'user/' . $node->uid, array('attributes' => array('title' => $profile->title, 'class' => 'micro'), 'html' => 'true'));
  $content .= l($profile->title, 'microblog/'. $node->uid, array('attributes' => array('class' => 'microname', 'title' => 'Микроблог - '. $profile->title)));
  $content .= check_markup($node->title, $format = 'Full HTML', $check = TRUE);
  $content .= '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
  $content .= '<p align="right">' . l(format_interval((time() - $node->created), 1, NULL), 'node/'. $node->nid) . ' назад</p>';
  $content .= '</div>';
  $content .= '<br />';  
  return $content;
}
```

The code above displays a CCK field (field_photo), but what happens if the user has an empty "field_photo"?
Would the following code work?

```
if ($profile->field_photo == TRUE) {
  $content .= l($ava, 'user/' . $node->uid, array('attributes' => array('title' => $profile->title, 'class' => 'micro'), 'html' => 'true'));
}
else {
  $noava = theme_imagecache('microblog', 'sites/default/files/imagecache/user_block_small/imagefield_default_images/no_photo.png');
}
```

Comment: Consider when asking questions if you question is truely about Drupal. What you have posted here would probably be a better fit on the stackoverflow site where you can ask question about programming. This is in a gray area since knowledge about CCK data is helpful to answer the question. So wont move it unless any one disagrees.

Comment: The question is specific for Drupal, as the code would work iff `$profile->field_photo` contain a boolean value and not, for example, an array. Knowing the datatype of that object field requires knowing Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!empty($profile->field_photo)) {...}
```

Should be able to work for you.

Comment: if (!empty($profile->field_photo) {
      $content .= l($ava, 'user/' . $node->uid, array(...);
      }
      else {
      $content .= l($noava, 'user/' . $node->uid, array(...);
      }

but it doesn't works. Still, when a user has empty field_photo - it displays nothing. (But must be a no_avatar.png image, when a user has no photo).